# client application with REST https call

Tags: java, rest, ssl, https

Suppose I am a java web server application  . I want a java client to be able to connect me from a java application by REST on https over the internet.
So I got my CA certificate and add it to my truststore and created my keystore.
My question is : Does the client application have to get anything from me (a file or any other information) in order to be able to establish  this connection (regarding this ssl issue I mean) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is signed by CA, client doesn't need anything else. If it is self-signed, client will need same certificate to compare.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? suppose it is a self-signed , should I send them the CA ? or other thing ?